# scenic highways within 120 miles of Kingston NY?

Tags: scenic-routes, new-york-state

We're taking a trip this weekend upstate and wanted to know what are some are scenic roadways within 120 miles of Kingston, New York. Not hiking footpaths - car roads. As well, what would be some of the highest elevated roadways we can drive thru.

Comment: Elevated road being a skyway or just the highest road elevation on a mountain?  And don't you think that 120 mile radius is a bit broad?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. One of the expectations of StackExchange is that you have attempted some research on your own; a simple web search on "scenic drive Kingston New York" turns up a number of suggestions from National Geographic and Lonely Planet among others. I encourage you to [edit](http://travel.stackexchange.com/posts/50875/edit) your post to include such information, A review of the [help center](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help) may also be recommendable.

Comment: @choster Thank you. I did briefly give a look on Google and I didn't find something. I wanted to perhaps get some pointers where to look into the right direction. I tried to broaden the question as much as possible for more options since we are open to traveling the distance to nice places. I edited the question and tried and make it sound more grammatically correct.

Comment: AAA's state road maps are nice for this purpose; they indicate scenic roads with a parallel line of green dots.  I'm not sure whether these are based on some official "scenic" designation, or some AAA staff member's opinion, or a combination thereof, but I've found them pretty accurate.

Comment: Who has physical maps these days? :) I'll check out AAA's website

Answer (score 2):

As Karlson notes, 120 miles is casting a fairly wide net.  This would include parts of Pennsylvania, New Jersey, Connecticut, Massachusetts, New Hampshire, and Vermont in addition to part of New York.

If you want to explore options in New York, you can visit the state Department of Transportation's page on the Scenic Byways program: https://www.dot.ny.gov/display/programs/scenic-byways/lists

There is a link on that page to a map, which will help you in planning yourtrip.